# Android, how to create an avd for arm64-v8a based on api 29

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I need to build my Android app for arm64-v8a devices using api 29. I see there isn't a "Google apis arm64 v8a System Image" for based on api 29.
Which is the right way to build an app for arm64-v8a devices version based on api 29?

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this?